# VMs Missing from Cluster list in DPM 2010

Tags: hyper-v, scdpm

We have a HA Hyper-V cluster with 8 nodes that we are backing up VIA DPM 2010.  As far as I can tell it is up to date with all the latest patches and the like.  Most things seem to run fine, however, when I try to create a new protection group or add members to an existing one several of the VMs do not appear in the list.  Any ideas what might be happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Are the VMs running as cluster services? Open Failover Cluster Manager and make sure all the VMs are there. If you create a VM in Hyper-V Manager it is not clustered, you must later add it to the cluster with the Failover Manager.

Also have you installed [KB975354-v2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975354) on the Hyper-V Servers?

Also are you using the Release Candidate or the RTM? If you have RTM, did you have the RC installed before?